# Add a left only border on hover CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm attempting to have an element show a left border when hovering over it. Currently I have it set to use a top border as a divider and the right, bottom and left borders are set to 0.

```
.post.reply {
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif !important;
        font-size: 8pt !important;
        background: #fafafa !important;
        color: #1a1a1a !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        border-bottom: 0 !important;
        border-top: 3 !important;
        border-left: 0 !important;
        border-right: 0 !important;
        border-color: #cecece !important;
    }
```

And this is the hover

```
.post.reply:hover {
        box-shadow: #444 0 0 0px !important;
        border-left: 4px !important;
    }
```

Other things work fine in the hover section, but the border refuses to show. I'm almost sure it's because I have it set 0 above, but shouldn't it be different on hover? Any help appreciated.

Comment: 1). You're not specifying units (like `px`) for your `border` rules. 2) You've got **way** too many `!important`s going on there.

Comment: I can understand the `!important` in the css especially if trying to work with a stubborn wordpress theme, or where the base css is overly complex.  `!important` or (not important) somehow translates into 'This is super important' in CSS.  If more people would make their themes's in wordpress more friendly to style, this would not be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your overall CSS should be and it'll work perfectly:

```
.post.reply {
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif !important;
        font-size: 8pt !important;
        background: #fafafa !important;
        color: #1a1a1a !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        border-top: 3px solid #cecece !important;
        border-bottom: none !important;
        border-left: none !important;
        border-right: none !important;
}

.post.reply:hover {
        box-shadow: #444 0 0 0px !important;
        border-left: 4px solid #cecece !important;
}
```

I have also created a quick **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5cvnw16/1/)** for you to see. Moreover, you should remove all the `!important`'s if you really don't need them.

Comment: Thanks. This helps, but it stills show the right, left and bottom borders on the original item.

Comment: @Fahad - you no longer need to use jsFiddle for this stuff as you can now embed runnable code in SO directly -- sandbox and all.

Comment: @Axioen It shouldn't display the right, left and bottom borders since we're only declaring `border-top` inside the CSS. You can also see the jsFiddle and it only shows the `border-top`. Are you using the exact CSS which I've written in my answer above?

Comment: @Fahad Yes, definitely. I'm not sure why. [Heres a screenshot.](http://i.imgur.com/byV40WC.png)

Comment: @Axioen Please check my updated answer and use that CSS. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. I'm a little upset I didn't think of trying it, I just assumed none and 0 would give the same result. Thanks a bunch man!

Comment: @axioen You're welcome. I believe there was already some CSS in your stylesheet which was displaying the `border-bottom`, `border-left` and the `border-right` for the `.post.reply ` element. It had to be cancelled out using `border-bottom: none !important;`, `border-left: none !important;` and `border-right: none !important;`.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple my friend; you declare it at the selector AND hover state!

```
#selectorID.reply:hover {
    border-left:solid 4px #ff0000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.post.reply {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 8pt !important;
  background: #fafafa !important;
  color: #1a1a1a !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  border-color: #cecece !important;
}
.post.reply:hover {
  box-shadow: #444 0 0 0px !important;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 4px !important;
}
/* for demo only */

html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: #327642;
}
.post {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post reply">
  Foo Bar
</div>
<div class="post reply">
  Foo Bar
</div>
<div class="post reply">
  Foo Bar
</div>
<div class="post reply">
  Foo Bar
</div>
<div class="post reply">
  Foo Bar
</div>
<div class="post reply">
  Foo Bar
</div>
```